# checkSession not returning profile, email or email_verified

Tags: authentication, auth0

In my application using auth0 I need to know if the email is verified. I have followed the documentation when using checkSession but it is still not returning the data I am querying for.

Here I am setting up the connection to my auth0 app

```
const webAuth = auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: 'my_domain',
    clientID: 'my_client_id',
    responseType: 'token', // code or token,
    redirectUri: 'my_redirect_uri',
           
  })
```

Here I am checking the session

```
 webAuth.checkSession({
   scope: 'openid profile email',}, function (err, authResult) {
   if(err) {
    console.log('err', err)
   }
    if(typeof authResult !== 'undefined') {
    console.log(authResult, 'authResult')
```

but it does not return a profile, email or email verified as it should according to the documentation